# Why is VLC verified every time I open a file that is supposed to open with it?

Tags: applications, vlc

I have downloaded VLC for Mac, and I installed it. Now every time I open a video that is supposed to be opened by VLC, it starts verifying again, like it is the first time and it will install it. I also don't see a shortcut in the Applications folder. What is the way around this?

Answer (score 6):

If your Applications folder doesn't contain VLC.app, you probably didn't install it properly. The verifying process (trying to start VLC) indicates that a dmg containing the app has to be opened.

Since VLC is a self-containing app you don't have to initiate an installation. Instead open the downloaded VLC.dmg, drag and drop the VLC.app inside the mounted dmg to the folder /Applications. Then unmount the dmg and start VLC.

Answer (score 2):

I had the exact same issue. I think it happened because I tried to open a video file using `Open With` while the VLC dmg was still mounted (even though I did properly install VLC to `/Applications/VLC.app`). Apparently it associated to the mounted dmg instead of `/Applications/VLC.app`.

The solution was simple:

- Unmount the VLC dmg.
- Run in a terminal: `killall Finder`

After this, using `Open With > VLC` associated to the proper `/Applications/VLC.app`, and did not go through the "verify" process every time.

Comment: I had the exact same issue.  In my case, all I had to do was to unmount the VLC disc image (which required a force unmount).  After that, 'open with' used the one in /Applications.